# Is there any guide for Directus 9 file storage adaptor for AWS S3 connections?

Tags: amazon-s3, directus

I am trying to connect AWS S3 for file storage of Directus 9. Could not find any information on how to edit .env file to do so.

Following is my file storage settings in .env

```
####################################################################################################
### File Storage

# A CSV of storage locations (eg: local,digitalocean,amazon) to use. You can use any names you'd like for these keys ["local"]
STORAGE_LOCATIONS="local,S3"
STORAGE_LOCAL_DRIVER="local"
STORAGE_LOCAL_ROOT="./uploads"

## S3 Example (location name: DigitalOcean)
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_DRIVER="s3"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_KEY="abcdef"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_SECRET="ghijkl"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_ENDPOINT="ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_BUCKET="my-files"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_REGION="ams3"

## Google Cloud Storage Example (location name: Google)
# STORAGE_GOOGLE_DRIVER="gcs"
# STORAGE_GOOGLE_KEY_FILENAME="abcdef"
# STORAGE_GOOGLE_BUCKET="my-files"

## AWS S3 Storage Settings (My settings)
STORAGE_S3_DRIVER="s3"
STORAGE_S3_KEY="******"
STORAGE_S3_SECRET="*******"
STORAGE_S3_BUCKET="*******"
STORAGE_S3_REGION="ap-south-1"
STORAGE_S3_ENDPOINT="s3.amazonaws.com"
STORAGE_S3_ROOT="/uploads"
#STORAGE_S3_ACL=
```

**Note: 'AWS S3 Storage Settings (My settings)' are settings for AWS S3 by me.**

**Following link is what I have discovered till now:**
https://docs.directus.io/getting-started/glossary.html#storage-adapters

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get working by following code:

Changes:

1. Removed "local" from STORAGE_LOCATIONS
2. Hide STORAGE_LOCAL_DRIVER and STORAGE_LOCAL_ROOT
3. Replaced S3 with AMAZON in My settings

```
####################################################################################################
### File Storage

# A CSV of storage locations (eg: local,digitalocean,amazon) to use. You can use any names you'd like for these keys ["local"]
STORAGE_LOCATIONS="amazon"
#STORAGE_LOCAL_DRIVER="local"
#STORAGE_LOCAL_ROOT="./uploads"

## S3 Example (location name: DigitalOcean)
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_DRIVER="s3"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_KEY="abcdef"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_SECRET="ghijkl"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_ENDPOINT="ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_BUCKET="my-files"
# STORAGE_DIGITALOCEAN_REGION="ams3"

## Google Cloud Storage Example (location name: Google)
# STORAGE_GOOGLE_DRIVER="gcs"
# STORAGE_GOOGLE_KEY_FILENAME="abcdef"
# STORAGE_GOOGLE_BUCKET="my-files"

## AWS S3 Storage Settings (My settings)
STORAGE_AMAZON_DRIVER="s3"
STORAGE_AMAZON_KEY="******"
STORAGE_AMAZON_SECRET="*******"
STORAGE_AMAZON_BUCKET="*******"
STORAGE_AMAZON_REGION="ap-south-1"
STORAGE_AMAZON_ENDPOINT="s3.amazonaws.com"
STORAGE_AMAZON_ROOT="/uploads"
#STORAGE_AMAZON_ACL=
```